# Audio streaming between 2 devices via bluetooth/wifi?

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, streaming

I need help making an app that works over bluetooth/wifi. I prefer using bluetooth since there won't be no lags.

Basically, what I want the app to do is stream audio from one device to another device. It has to be accurate.

Any help?(I am willing to pay for the man that helps me).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> All of the above is just the beginning. The API allows your iPhone to
>   stream data from the service once it is discovered and connected to,
>   etc. Just like the older Bluetooth spec, but simpler. In the spec’s
>   simplicity lies its power.

for details please have a look at [LINK](http://dedegroup.tumblr.com/post/14177518904/bluetooth) here.